# std::istream extract operator (double or float) are very slow in VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, istream

I make a migration from VS2008 to VS2012 and I see very slow performance on the VS2012 version.

The problem are in the extraction operator of the  input stream.
istream& operator>> (float& val);
istream& operator>> (double& val);

These function on a text file is twice slower on VS2012.

For example, the following code retrieve 3.75 seconde for VS2012 and only 1.25 seconde for VS2008.

Can you tell me why?

thanks in advance.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

#define FILE_NAME "D:\\test_Roadmap.txt"

const int NB_VALUE = 1000000;
const int NB_MESURE = 20;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  std::cout<<"ecriture"<<std::endl;
  //ecriture
  {
    std::ofstream ostream (FILE_NAME);
    float val = 0.f;

    for (int ii=0; ii<NB_VALUE; ii++)
    {
      ostream << val;
      ostream << " ";
      val += 0.04f;
    }

  }

  std::cout<<"lecture"<<std::endl;
  //lecture
  double texec = 0;
  for (int iMesure=0; iMesure<NB_MESURE; iMesure++)
  {
    std::ifstream istream (FILE_NAME);
    float val = 0;

    time_t tbegin1 = time(NULL);

    for (int ii=0; ii<NB_VALUE; ii++)
    {
      istream>> val;
    }

    time_t tbegin2 = time(NULL);

    texec += difftime(tbegin2,tbegin1);   

  }
  texec /= NB_MESURE;

  std::ostringstream oss1;
  oss1 << texec;
  std::string s1 = std::string(" read : ") + oss1.str() + std::string(" in s");
  std::cout<<s1<<std::endl;

  float a;
  std::cin>>a;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you testing a debug build or a release build?

Comment: is it in release for VS2008 and VS2012

Answer (score 1):

The link below states that the extraction operator "Extracts and parses characters sequentially from the stream to interpret them as the representation of a value of the proper type.."

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

So what I believe is the implementation of extraction operator to float or double value in VS2012 is very slow, as it is sequentially parsing and interpreting characters to numbers. Recently, I experienced the same issue in VS2012 while the code runs 7 times faster in VS2010 compilation. I was able to get around the issue by using extraction operator ">>" with char[] instead of double or float, and then using atof() to get the double value.

Below is the code snippet that worked for me,

```
char inStr[64];
float val = 0;

std::ifstream istream (FILE_NAME);

istream >> inStr;
val = atof(inStr);
```